# Socket.io: Live Chat Design, better way to initialize list of rooms and people?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, chat

I am trying to create a meeting app using `socket` and `node`. So far, following this tutorial (https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-realtime-room-chat-app-using-node-webkit-socket-io-and-mean) I see that they are making the list of available users to chat using Mongo.

My meeting app consists of available rooms and people (so there are list of rooms available and list of people that is inside a room, or not anywhere in the room, you cannot chat with people that is not in a room yet). Is it better if I make the list of rooms and people in just a variable and not on database (and is it possible that new people joining have access to that variable)? And if indeed using variable, how many concurrent user connection that can connect at same time, like should I allow only 1000 users connect at same time if I'm using variable method?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you continue to use MongoDB. You would not actually store the connections though. You would want to store the room IDs (along with their name, description, etc.) and user IDs. In the Users collection, you would also store their name, bio, online/offline status, etc. Either you build a new document every time a new user connects, or you implement some sort of authentication system so users can login in from multiple sources.

If you use MongoDB, you really don't have to worry about having too many people online. It can handle whatever you give it.